# Especificar Consulta de búsqueda tipo

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un pequeño problema: necesito una función que me ayude a seleccionar solo datos explícitos.

Ejemplo. En el campo `TIPO` tengo

```
 boleta 12 
 ticket 
 E-boleta
 factura 13
 Pedido
 boleta 23
 factura 2
```

Solo quiero que me muestre los que inicien con:

```
 boleta 
 factura
```

como podría ser mi procedimiento. Alguna pista por favor y que tengan un buen día abrazos.

```
select sucursal.nombre,venta.mov, count(*) [Total Comprobante] from venta 
(nolock)
left outer join sucursal (nolock) on venta.sucursal = sucursal.sucursal
left outer join movtipo on venta.mov = movtipo.mov and movtipo.modulo = 
'vtas' and movtipo.clave in 
('vtas.fb','vtas.f','vtas.fc','vtas.fg','vtas.d','vtas.dc','vtas.b')
where 
movtipo.clave in 
('vtas.fb','vtas.f','vtas.fc','vtas.fg','vtas.d','vtas.dc','vtas.b') and
FechaEmision >= '2018-01-01' and FechaEmision < '2018-01-31'
group by sucursal.nombre,venta.mov
```

Comment: Pero intentaste algo? solo queres que sea LIKE algo?

Comment: en si en un contador de boletas y facturas  pero me esta trabando en separar , y solo necesito una función que me separe o seleccione solo boletas y facturas mas no los que empiezan con E_ o  ticket |, si me dejo entender

Comment: que probaste hasta ahora?

Comment: select sucursal.nombre,venta.mov, count(*) [Total Comprobante] from venta (nolock)
left outer join sucursal (nolock) on venta.sucursal = sucursal.sucursal
left outer join movtipo on venta.mov = movtipo.mov and movtipo.modulo = 'vtas' and movtipo.clave in ('vtas.fb','vtas.f','vtas.fc','vtas.fg','vtas.d','vtas.dc','vtas.b')
where 
movtipo.clave in ('vtas.fb','vtas.f','vtas.fc','vtas.fg','vtas.d','vtas.dc','vtas.b') and
FechaEmision >= '2018-01-01' and FechaEmision < '2018-01-31'
group by sucursal.nombre,venta.mov

Comment: usa el boton [edit] y agregalo en la pregunta...

Answer (score 1):

Buen día.

Puedes utilizar el operador [`like`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) para hacer un `select` que te devuelva las filas que te interesan.

La idea básica del `like` es encontrar registros que sean *similares* a un patrón. Los caracteres `%` y `_` son *comodines* (*wilcards* en inglés) y tienen un significado especial:

- `%` coincidirá con cualquier secuencia de caracteres (cero, uno o más)
- `_` coincidirá con un caracter cualquiera, exactamente uno.

Así las cosas, podemos encontrar coincidencias de cadenas que inicien con un `'valor'` determinado utilizando el patrón `'valor%'`.

Aterrizando las ideas, puedes encontrar todos los registros que inicien con la palabra factura haciendo algo como:

```
select *
  from miTabla
 where tipo like 'factura%';
```

La coincidencia entre mayúsculas y minúsculas estará determinada por el *collate* de la columan `tipo`. Si es *case insensitive*, también conicidiría una cadena tal como `'FACTURA 56'`.

**Edición**

Ahora que has añadido tu consulta, quiero añadir que puedes añadir directamente al `where` dos condiciones `like`, por ejemplo, asumiendo que el campo tipo está en la tabla venta, esto haría el trabajo:

```
 where ...
   and (venta.tipo like 'factura%' or venta.tipo like 'boleta%')
 group by ...
```

Finalmente, no está relacionado con tu pregunta, pero no veo sentido a que en el `select` hagas un `left outer join` con la tabla `movtipo` si luego vas a filtrar solo ciertos valores de una columna de dicha tabla en el `where`. Haz directamente un `inner join`, además eso te ahorra poner el filtro es el mismo en el `join` que en el `where`.

Otro tema que he visto que mucha gente utiliza indiscriminadamente es el uso del *hint* `(nolock)`. ¿sabes realmente lo que estás haciendo con eso?. Si no lo sabes, por favor, investiga.

Comment: gracias me sirve , pero una consulta se puede agregar dos like, los estaba asiendo de la siguiente manera: where tipo like 'factura%' and tipo like 'boleta%'

Comment: @Many, edité mi respuesta para incluir un ejemplo antes que tu pusieras ese comentario. Por favor actualizala y creo que te quedará claro. Un saludo.

Comment: jejejejeje, muchas gracias me sirvió para el primer paso ahora , ahora tengo una idea para armar el cursor o un trigger.